# Wifi disconnects automatically on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, proxy

[image: lshw -C network output - intel wireless device]

My wifi disconnects automatically at certain intervals. Shows a question mark symbol over the wifi when it happens. After I restart my router the wifi works fine. But I don't know what is the issue with my laptop. I have Windows and Ubuntu installed. Is there a way to check the system configurations and check the issue? I'm new to Ubuntu.

Model: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of your computer as well as the output of `sudo lshw -C network`? This will make it much more likely that someone can answer the question 

Comment: We'd also like to see: `nmcli device wifi list` The fact that restarting the router resores connectivity suggests that we might tweak the settings in the router. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.